# Interface Bulder and XCode: change color of a view "top bar"

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface, builder

I have a couple of views in my iPhone app.
each view shows a "top bar" in blue, I haven't added a "Navigation Bar", simply edited what's on the inspector "View Controller" section and gave it a title. (this section: http://img69.imageshack.us/i/schermata20101001a22014.png/)

Is it possible to change the color of this bar that'a automatically added on top of other View Items? or even to hide it? both In Interface Builder or in Code,
thanks.

Comment: I have yet to see any of the "built-in" bars set up in Interface Builder actually appear when you run the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to change the one added automatically, I assume that you'll have to make your own to change things such as the color, which you can do easily with the tint option in the attributes panel.

Comment: yeah, I mor or less know how to change a "custom" navigation bar...but I would like to change the "automatic" one... thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

It's the navigation bar from the UINavigationController. You can do stuff like `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]` and `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor magentaColor]`.

You should not set the navigationBar.hidden/alpha directly, since those are handled by the UINavigationController. Additionally, UINavigationController may not re-layout your views appropriately.